# SharePoint: How to have a unique constraint in a list?

Tags: sharepoint, duplicate-data

In SQL its possible to have fields that cannot contain duplicate data.

How is this possible in SharePoint?

Lets say you have a list containing values like

```
ORANGES
APPLES 
PEARS
```

How do you ensure that the user cannot enter

```
ORANGES
APPLES 
PEARS
ORANGES
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done out of the box. But there are these community solutions:

- [SPListConstraints](http://www.spelements.com/splistconstraints/) (free but not open source)
- [Unique Column Policy](http://www.codeplex.com/features) (open source, original solution by [Scot Hillier](http://www.shillier.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11))

Comment: Note: Scot's blog seems to be having some auth issues at the moment. You can read more about his solution on this page: http://www.shillier.com/default.aspx?Paged=TRUE&p_PublishedDate=20090501%2012%3A38%3A59&p_ID=15&View={86C4766F-C635-4F56-BC26-52BFDD3DF7A4}&PageFirstRow=6

Comment: Ah - thats typical of JokePoint err I mean SharePoint, I would be dissappointed if it didn't fail me each and every time. Thank you though for your answer.

Comment: Grrr - and SO's auto hyperlinking doesn't work. Search on the web and you will find his article! http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unique+site%3Ashillier.com

Comment: @JL: Completely understand your frustrations. Note that the 2007 version is almost 3 years old and has come a long way since the previous SPS 2003 bringing a huge number of features. The fact that it is so extensible and devs like us can create these solutions that significantly improve it is a credit to the product's design.

Comment: Alex - do you think MOSS 2010 will have constraints?

Comment: @JL: There's been nothing mentioned publicly about this so it's too early to say. SharePoint 2010 will make life easier for developers however, see http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/2010/Sneak_Peek/Pages/Developer-Video.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this can be done in 2010

If you go to your list settings and click on the column there is the option "Enforce unique values"